# The mystery of '$.md5 is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, md5

I have a js code that uses jQuery.MD5 library. It works perfectly on my server:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://example.com/static/js/jquery.md5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
      // my code goes here (declaring variables and functions)
      var code = $.md5('mystring');
      // and a little more code
    </script>
</body>
```

But then I upload it to a web application (which I cannot control), that makes it look like this and puts it into an iframe:

```
<head>
  <script>
    // some extra variables are declared here
    // double-checked that nothing here can break my code
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://example.com/static/js/jquery.md5.js"></script>
    <script>
        // some code
        var code = $.md5('mystring');
        // some code
    </script>
</body>
```

And this code starts giving me the `$.md5 is not a function` error. Strange thing. Tried clearing the cache, putting jquery.md5.js code directly into mine, nothing works.

Note that **all the code works on my machine, so there must be no problem with my JS**.

Update: *the problematic code behavior seems to be unpredictable, meaning that sometimes it works fine with no changes.*

What can be wrong?

Comment: Well it's certainly possible that the initial block of "some code" could break things, but we can't see whether that's true because it's not in the question.

Comment: @Pointy sorry, forgot to add this. There I declare functions and variables, nothing special. Checked that too. Not sure if it's a good idea to put my full code here, because it's too complex

Comment: Just to narrow down the possibilities here, if you use the webapp's page structure (with the script tags inside the body, and the extra variables in the head) outside an iframe, does it throw the same error?

Comment: Can we see jquery.md5.js? You've used example.com in your sample above

Comment: You could always add a `console.log($)` before the attempt to use the md5 code, just to make sure it's still a jQuery reference.

Comment: @DanielBeck yes, it does

Comment: @Pointy, it is, I had checked that

Comment: @Scoots check this github repo: https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5

Comment: Hm.  Copying your second block of code exactly, except for using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5/master/jquery.md5.js instead of the example.com URL, appears to work for me; no error message, and `code` gets the value 169319501261c644a58610f967e8f9d0.

Comment: @DenielBeck, just retried doing that, and it seems to work for me too. I mean, running the problematic code as local file. So damn strange. And here comes another mystery. The whole thing works sometimes, but it's behavior is unpredictable. One minute it works, and another it does not, with no changes in code or variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... That's a little embarrassing, but the problem was in jQuery. The one I included in my iframe conflicted with the one included in the page. Somehow this lead to "hiding" my $.md5 function after its code's end.

And yeah, I know, it was quite obvious that jQuery could cause problems.

Comment: Never use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page. Your **problem** is extremely common and due to the fact that people are including multiple versions (or even the same version more than once) on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery md5 function you should have import **jquery.md5.js** file in your project.

Steps-

1. Download **jquery.md5.js** file from https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5
2. Copy this file into your source folder. (ex: assert/theme/js)
3. Import that js file to your project.
   (ex: `<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>/public/assert/theme/js/jquery.md5.js"></script>`

)

That's it! You are done!