# jquery blur methods does not work with angular ng-view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am a newbie to the angular jquery world. I am writing a Single Page app with nav-bars that works with a couple of REST-API's.

I have an index.html page where I have imported all the `js` scripts needed for my application(and its subpage/divs)

The subpage (a div page) gets loaded inside the `<div ng-view>` when a particular nav-bar gets created. I have implemented a `.blur()` method for a couple of form elements which I hope to use it to call some REST APIs. But the `.blur` method doesnt seem to get invoked at all when the form element goes out of scope. I have inspected that the js file is loaded. It also doesnt throw any errors in the console.

I tried moving the `<script>` importing the `jquery-blurs.js` to the particular div which results in the blur function getting called but then I get warning in the console and I get errors for $.md5() not found which from this post [[The mystery of '$.md5 is not a function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618236/the-mystery-of-md5-is-not-a-function]) I understand is due to different versions of jquery.

Any help is appreciated.

> index.html

```
  <html lang="en" ng-app="masterApp">
   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="container">

  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">TestAPP</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>


        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Schedules <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#past_schedules">Past/Current Schedules status</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Future Schedules</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Requires Admin access</li>
              <li><a href="#new_schedule">Create Schedule</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Manage Schedules</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div ng-view></div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-dateformat.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-blurs.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

> jquery-blurs.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var date_str = "";
$("#ID").blur(function(){
    console.log($("#ID").val());
    var id = $("#ID").val();
    if (id == "") {
        return;
    }
    $.getJSON("http://my-rest-api-url.com" + $("#ID").val()
    )
        .done(function(data){
            if(data.msg != "") {
                alert("Verify ID \n" + data.msg);
                location.reload();
            }
            var comment = data.teams.names[0] + ' vs ' + data.teams.names[1];
            console.log($.md5(comment));
            date_str = $.format.date(data.date, "yyyy.MM.ddTHH.mm.ss")
            $('#start_datetime').val(date_str);
            var markup = '<tr name="entry"> <td>' +
                data.date +
                '</td><td>' +
                    $.md5(comment) +
                    '</td><td>' +
                data.teams.names[0] + ' vs ' + data.teams.names[1] +
                '</td><td></tr>';
            $("table tbody").empty();
            $("table tbody").eq(0).append(markup);
            $("#program_id").val($.md5(comment));
            $("#comment").val(comment)
            $("#sport").val(data.sport)
            $("#broadcast_id").val($("#StreamID").val() + '_' + $("#program_id").val() + '_' + date_str)
            console.log($("#broadcast_id").val())
        })
});    
});
```

Comment: You should really consider either using Angular's way of modifying the DOM (through state changes) *or* jQuery's direct manipulation of the DOM, not both. See ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14994391)

Comment: Thanks Mike, I just did not know what keywords to search for, for my problem. I have familiarity with jQuery and complete newbie to angular. I didnt realize angular's ngBlur could be effectively used as well.